# haskell hmatrix installation under windows 10

Tags: hmatrix

I read all the related subjects on the net (including stackoverflow) and tried to follow clossely their advice, but nothing helps.
here is my setup:
windows 10.
gcc 8.2.2
[image: My LAPAC directory]

My command file (ran under normal cmd of windows and under mingw terminal, with the same results):

cabal install hmatrix --flag hmatrix --extra-lib-dirs=C:\LAPAC\lib --extra-include-dirs=C:\LAPAC\include

the results:
[image]

I need a simple, straight forward, procedure to install the hmatrix.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem over and over again. I tried the installation many times following all advice that I found on the web.

I came to the conclusion, that hmatrix cannot run under Windows 10.

I hope the developers will fix that issue. For now, I give up...